# angular.js ui + bootstrap typeahead + asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using typeahead with the angular.js directive but my function to populate the autocomplete makes an asynchronous call and I can't return it to populate the autocomplete. Is there anyway to make it work with this asynchronous call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can I assume that you are using the typeahead of Bootstrap 2.x ?

If so, in the documentation, the description of the `source` field of `typeahead()`'s options is this:

> The data source to query against. May be an array of strings or a
>   function. The function is passed two arguments, the query value in the
>   input field and the process callback. The function may be used
>   synchronously by returning the data source directly or asynchronously
>   via the process callback's single argument.

You can definitely pass in an async function as the `source` attr. The `source` function could be something like:

```
function someFunction(query, process) {
  someAsyncCall(...query or so... , function(res) { // success callback
    process(res);
  }, function(err) {                                // error callback
    process(null);
  });
}
```

**Update:**

If you are using Angular Bootstrap's typeahead, it should be even easier. According to Angular Bootstrap's docs(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you can just return a promise for the `typeahead` function. Some example from the docs:

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
  return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params: {
      address: val,
      sensor: false
    }
  }).then(function(res){
    var addresses = [];
    angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
      addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
    });
    return addresses;
  });
};
```

A simpler one could be:

```
$scope.getSomething= function(query) {
  var promise = $http.get('...some url...', {
    params: {
      queryName: query
    }
  });
  return promise;
};
```

Or you can build your own promise:

```
$scope.getSomething= function(query) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  someAsyncCall(...query or so... , function(res) { // success callback
    deferred.resolve(res);
  }, function(err) {                                // error callback
    deferred.reject(err);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Actually, many services like `$http` are just returning promises when you call them.
More about promise in AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Actually I'm doing this: <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCard"
      placeholder="Card Name"
      typeahead="cardName for cardName in cardSearch($viewValue)"
      typeahead-loading="loading" class="form-control"
      typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-wait-ms="400">

Comment: @LuizGuilherme That's even easier. According to Angular Bootstrap's doc, you can just return a promise if you want to do async call.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do that? What would be a promise?